# Функция для нахождения среднего арифметического массивов

Tags: javascript

```
var arr1 = [0];
var arr2 = [1, 2, 3];
var arr3 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var arr4 = [1, 4, 4, 4, 1];
var arr5 = [-12, -13, 512, 1337];

function average(arr) {
  console.log("The average of");
  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
  }
   console.log("is: " );
};
```

Не получается найти среднее арифметическое этих массивов. Хотел через `.reduce()`, но в этой онлайн-игрушке (**JSdares**, игрушка из 2013) она не подходит (просит перенести код на новую строчку в самом методе `reduce`).
Тут смысл такой, что "чем меньше код, тем лучше".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544371/finding-the-average-of-an-array-using-js/29544442

Comment: Ну перенос строки внутри reduce как-бы и не запрещен. С переносом строки будет всё равно короче, чем обычный цикл)

Comment: @timur `console.log(eval(a.join('+'))/a.length)` :)))